# Everywhere vs. Anywhere

Tags: adverbial-phrases

Nowadays all merchants of Westeros sell dragonglass. So you can find it ____ .

A.Everywhere

B.Anywhere

Which fits better A, B or both ?

I know A is true, but B also makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both options could be correct.

Usually, "anywhere" refers to a place that you are unsure of or one that doesn’t matter, while "everywhere" refers to all places.

In your case, "everywhere" seems better to me as you stress out that the glass is vastly spread and may be found in virtually every shop. But "anywhere" here would deliver an identical meaning, so feel free to use whichever option you prefer.

Comment: you can find it in every shop or any shop?

Comment: I have updated the answer as it was rather erroneous. "Every shop" would mean all the shops there are, and "any shop" would mean that no matter what shop you walk in, you will find the dragonglass there. Here both share the same meaning, there is no difference to me.